# Monte Carlo convergence sample size

Tags: monte-carlo

I'm studying Monte Carlo analysis but I find very counter-intuitive the computation of the minimum sample size in order to reach a certain level of precision. As stated in `Montecarlo methods in Financial Engineering`, such sample size comes from the CLT and it can be computed according to

$n = \frac{z^2_{\delta/2} \sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$

My experiment is the classic bernoulli variable, with $p$ probability of success.
Suppose my level of precision is $0.01$, then my $z_{0.01/2} = 2.57$.

I consider three cases.

$p=0.1\%$

$p=1\%$

$p=10\%$

With $\sigma^2 = p(1-p)$, I get

$n_{10\%} = 2.57^2 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.9 / 0.01^2 = 5944$

$n_{1\%} = 2.57^2 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.99 / 0.01^2 = 654$

$n_{0.1\%} = 2.57^2 \cdot 0.001 \cdot 0.999 / 0.01^2 =  66$

Intuitevely I would think the rarer the event, the greater the number of the simulations needed in order to approach the theoretical mean.
What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You are holding the level of precision fixed, so it is easier to approximate whatever distribution has the smallest variance.  The rarer the event, the smaller the absolute variance.

Comment: So, in order to scale the precision parameter to get always a 1% precision around the true value, should I put 

    a)  1% of 10%  = 0.001
    b)  1% of 1%    = 0.0001 
    c)  1% of 0.1% = 0.00001

in the denominator?